# I can't get to the skype contact page

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have logged on to Skype with my name and password but cannot to get to the contacts page, I have tried to navigate away from this page but it won't let me

Comment: can you please explain the situation a little more? are you having problems with your internet or think you have a virus or? what is the link you are trying to get to, and what do u need out of the contact page?

Comment: Elaine, would you be able to diagnose any issue if some one said, `I open a program but can't click on a button?` Please provide more detail. I assume Skype opens (what version), can you do anything at all with it? I mean, can you call etc. Please [edit your post](http://superuser.com/posts/644739/edit) and  try and explain as much as possible. @Sickest what has a virus got to do with this? Your comment adds no value.

Comment: maybe she has malware issues and her browser isn't functioning properly? Is it so hard to believe that malware or a virus could prevent her from browsing the web correctly? no.. that's crazy talk =\
im just trying to get her to explain the situation a little more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Skype app in Windows 8, contacts are called people.
When you select people, all of your contacts are displayed.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12110/finding-your-way-around-skype-for-windows-8